# What is the work done by friction on a body from the perspective of different observers using the formula $-μmgl$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, work, friction

Consider two observers moving with respect to each other at a speed $v$ along a straight line. They observe a block of mass $m$ moving a distance $l$ on a rough surface.
The change in KE of the block is different to the different observers in this case. Here "work done by friction= change in KE" i.e. it is different to different observers.
How to solve the same using "work done by friction= -μmgl"? It appears to me that by the 2nd way the answer is coming different. As μ, m, g and l are constants, the work done by friction will be the same to the different observers. Please resolve the controversy.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $l$ is not a constant. The different observers measure different values for $l$. The discrepancy in the change in KE is entirely explained by this disagreement on $l$.

So, for a block undergoing a frictional force of $-\mu m g$ starting at $x(0)=0$ with an initial velocity of $v(0)=\dot x(0)=v_0$ we get $$x(t)=-\frac{1}{2}\mu g t^2 + v_0 t$$ so at every point in time the change in KE is $$\Delta KE = \frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot x (t)^2-\dot x(0)^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\mu^2 m g^2 t^2-\mu m g v_0 t$$ and the other formula is $$ -\mu m g l = - \mu m g x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\mu^2 m g^2 t^2-\mu m g v_0 t$$ which is always equal to the change in KE.

Comment: There's an opportunity to make this answer even clearer and more useful by considering the paths and apparent changes in velocity for a friction-braked 1 kg block that appears to transition from 3 m/s to 1 m/s, from 2 m/s to 0 m/s (in the frame of the rough surface), and 1 m/s to -1 m/s, for instance.

Comment: @Chemomechanics good idea, but I will do it symbolically instead of for a specific numerical example